# Calling function of an linked list object defined inside another object

Tags: c++, object, linked-list, stack, queue

OK well I have two classes that I'm working with here.

Queue object and Stack object.

Queue is actually a linked list consisting of a head node and the next node.

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node(const T& data, Node* n = 0)
    {
        element = data;
        next = n;
    }

    T element;
    Node* next;
};

/*The head of the queue*/
Node* head;
```

like so....

Now Queue has functions that I have already implemented

```
friend ostream& operator<< <T>(ostream&,Queue<T>&);

/*The default constructor*/
Queue();

/*The copy constructor*/
Queue(const Queue<T>& other);

Queue<T>& operator=(const Queue<T>& other);

/*The destructor*/
~Queue();

void enqueue(const T& el);

T dequeue();

void increasePriority(const T& el);

bool isEmpty();
```

They all work...

So I get to the Stack class

```
Queue<T>* queue;
```

This is what a Stack is defined as...

The problem is calling these functions with a Stack object

```
friend ostream& operator<< <T>(ostream&,Stack<T>&);

/*The constructor for the Stack class*/
Stack();

/*The copy constructor*/
Stack(const Stack<T>& other);

Stack<T>& operator=(const Stack<T>& other);

~Stack();

void push(const T& el);

T pop();

T peek();

bool isEmpty();
```

How would I implement these functions so that they use the Queue objects functions?

In other words. The Constructor of Stack class must call the Queue class's constructor etc...

Comment: You can simplify your life by using `std::stack`, `std::deque` and `std::list`.  They are standard, already written and already tested!

Comment: SOLVED: All you I had to do was to call the Queue constructor from the Stack constructor like so ...
    Stack<T> :: Stack()
    {
        queue = Queue<T>();
    }

Comment: Thomas Matthews... I'm not allowed to :)

Comment: Do remember to post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As the OP suggested, this can be achieved by calling the Queue constructor from the Stack constructor like so:

```
Stack<T> :: Stack() { queue = Queue<T>(); }
```